# How to return multiple SELECT statements from VBA Excel

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have a VBA procedure setup within Excel to take some text inserted into an Excel tab and send it in as command text for a SQL query to complete.

However, in my query I have 3 different tables that I want to return separately (hence the 3 different connections in my VBA code).

Is there a way to use my query to return the three different tables so I don't have to run the query 3 separate times just to grab a different select statement at the end?

End of Query code:

```
SELECT * FROM #MailMergeFormatStep1
SELECT * FROM #MailMergeFormatStep2
SELECT * FROM #MailMergeFormatStep3
```

I want the results from each of these select statements to be ran and returned into a separate table connection in Excel.

Code:

```vb
Sub UploadCheckerQuery()

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("UploadCheckerConnection1").ODBCConnection.CommandText = Sheets("SQL1").Range("A5:A400").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("UploadCheckerConnection1").Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("UploadCheckerConnection2").ODBCConnection.CommandText = Sheets("SQL2").Range("A5:A400").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("UploadCheckerConnection2").Refresh

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("UploadCheckerConnection3").ODBCConnection.CommandText = Sheets("SQL3").Range("A5:A400").Value
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("UploadCheckerConnection3").Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: Do they all return different data?

Comment: Yes. They return 2 columns and in the same format but have been categorized differently. They will not share values.

Comment: Sounds like it is your logic that dictates you have three SELECT statments that accidently have the same format. You'll just have to do all three of them.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie I need them to be returned to different tables because someone has to do a mail merge off of each table (Different e-mail template for each table's results)

Comment: So do three queries. They need to return different pieces of data and used in different processes.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes that is what I currently have I was just wondering if there is a way to make it return multiple select statements from a single query into separate tables. That was the gist of my whole post.

Comment: No that isn't possible. A query returns a single result set. You could create a stored procedure that can return multiple result sets but I doubt it is going to be worth the effort. The performance from the sql side of things would be no different. It would still have to execute three queries. I would just stick with what you have right now as any change in the direction you are thinking is going to result in a lot of work with no benefit.

Comment: @SeanLange Got it. The query run for a pretty small amount of time each so it isn't too bad to run them all separately, I was just thinking if it was possible to optimize.

Comment: You seem to be selecting all columns and all rows from three different tables. There is nothing to optimize there. ;)

Comment: _"multiple select statements from a single query"_ Well, since the semi-colon is the SQL statement terminator, you could try to concatenate the three Select queries into one string and run that SQL "query" but I would have no idea what/which querie the server returns, so tellling it where to put which result remains a mistery to me.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly possible to return multiple recordsets from a single query - that's what the ADO command NextRecordset is for. The full details are [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/nextrecordset-method-ado?view=sql-server-2017)  but briefly just join the queries using :   "SELECT * FROM table1;SELECT * FROM table2".  However the multiple recordsets have to be on the same connection.

```
 Dim rs as new recordset
 set rs = connections(1).execute("Select * from table1:select * from table2)
 msgbox rs(0)
 rs.nextrecordset
 msgbox rs(0)
```

Comment: The SELECT * statements are coming from a large query that I have stored in an Excel tab for microsoft query to take as command text. I then have 3 temp tables that I create in that query that I would like to return the data from. How would this vba code know to take from that large query?

Comment: Sorry can't help on that part - ADO will return the data but I've no idea how Excel does connections.